# Combobox not getting focus in JTable - Java 8

Tags: java, swing, java-8, jtable, jcombobox

I have a code that used to work in Java 7, but it is not working anymore in Java 8.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    getChargesTable().changeSelection(row, col, false, false);
                    if (getChargesTable().editCellAt(row, col))
                    {
                        Component editor = getChargesTable().getEditorComponent();
                        editor.requestFocusInWindow();
                    }
                }
            });
```

In JAVA 8 the code above only works when debugging. See the result below when I debugged the code:

[image: result when debugging]

However, I got this result in a regular run:

[image: result in regular run]

As you can see, the combo box in JTable is not select in the second result.

It's weird because it used to work in Java 7. Can someone help me on that?

Thank you,

Comment: Post your [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: What camickr said, though I'd prefer a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) to be honest. We're not seeing at what point and in what context you are running that bit of code. Also you did not mention anything about your OS + OS version, which might be relevant information. Also JSE/JDK version?

Comment: @tt a SSCCE and an MCVE are the same thing, just different descriptions to explain the same concept. I also prefer the SSCCE explanation but this forum makes it easy to just using [] around "mcve" and it embeds the link for you, so I have gotten lazy.

Comment: Daniel, have you tried setting the focus to the table itself first (by `JTable.requestFocusInWindow`) and then start editing (`editCellAt`). AFAICT that should give focus to the editor component. In any case, without having a small reproduction program (minimal, compilable that shows the problem) it is hard to give any clear advice. If you can come up with such an MCVE or SSCCE as wel call it, you can [edit] your question, copy/paste the program in the question and format using the `{}` button.